# request.remoteAddress giving local IP in scala

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a Scala play framework application on Heroku. I want to get remote host IP address but println(request.remoteAddress) gives 10.165.120.180 which seems to be local IP.

Comment: Question is simple, but ideally clear what's the problem, no reason to close and/or downvote it!

Comment: This question is perfectly fine. Why the down votes?

Answer (score 3):

Heroku uses proxy servers for applications, that's why you get local machine's IP, instead you need to read common header named `X-Forwarded-For`, see the **[Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers)** also **[wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)** for more details.

> `X-Forwarded-For`: the originating IP address of the client connecting to the Heroku router

Answer (score 1):

Starting play 2.4.x, we configure `trustedProxies` instead ([play doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/HTTPServer#Configuring-trusted-proxies)), then `remoteAddress` as well as `secure` flag will be set correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set `play.http.forwarded.trustedProxies` to your list of trusted proxies. The default value of this setting is the loopback, i.e., `["127.0.0.1", "::1"]`, which basically means trust only loopback. It certainly doesn't work for many situations (most situations indeed).

If you don't know (or care) about what are your trusted proxies, set it to "trust all" most likely is what you want, like this:

```
play.http.forwarded.trustedProxies=["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
```

It's [documented well in 2.5.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/HTTPServer#trusting-all-proxies) but applies to 2.4.x too. One may get lucky without setting it using play version 2.4.3 or before. However there's [a pull request change](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/5266) that back-ported a fix to `2.4.4` that changed the previous 2.4.x behavior. This might give your a surprise.